# POST Form without a redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I would like to `post` a form's data to the page where the database-query will be made.

But I don't want like in normal cases where a new page opens up, or the site gets redirected. It should be something like a "hidden" post.

I tried to use a `xmlhttp-request (GET)` with a URL, but since there are a lot of form-fields where you can enter a few sentences of text, the URL gets super long.

I also heard about the "POST" `xmlhttp-request`, but I haven't found a good tutorial with a working example.

I don't want to use jQuery or anything like that.

Does anybody know how to do this, or how xmlhttp post works?

Here is the code I used for GET: (**BUT I would like to not do the `var ID1 = ...` part. I want to just get the values by `$_POST` like a regular `submit`.**

```
function doGET() {
    var ID1 = document.getElementByID("Textfield1").value;
    var ID2 = document.getElementByID("Textfield2").value;
    var ID3 = document.getElementByID("Checkbox1").value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystate = function() { alert(msg); }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.php?ID1=" + ID1 + "&ID2" + ID2 + "&ID3=" + ID3, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

HTML

```
<div>    
     <p> TEXT1 </p>     
     <Input type="TextBox" id="Textfiel1">    
     <br>
     <p> TEXT2 </p>
     <Input type="TextBox" id="Textfield2">
     <br>
     <p> Checkbox 1</p>    
     <Input type="Checkbox" id="checkbox1">
     <br>
     <Label onclick="doGET()"> Click </Label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are sending the GET request with?

Comment: you can't not use jquery and expect things to get easier.

Comment: @EisaAdil: You can choose not to use jQuery. Anything you can do in jQuery can be done in plain ordinary JS.

Comment: @jwir3 Yes, but with a lot lesser readability and a lot more code. But that's a personal pref.

Comment: @crush i havent done it, but there are 31 Form elements, 25 are text (255 chars) this would make a link like :

`/insert.php?ID1= veryveryverylongtext &ID2= secondlongtext &ID3= number123435843958435 &ID4=0101010101.....` imagine how long that gets...

Comment: You said, "i tried to use an `xmlhttp-request (GET)` with an URL`". Can you show us the code you tried for that? In return, we will show you how to modify it for a `POST` request.

Comment: @crush ok i will make a snipped

Comment: Can you also show us the `HTML` form?

Comment: @ggzone The OP specifically said no jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

Sending a `POST` request is not much different than sending a `GET`. There are two key differences, though, that I will point out below:

Since you didn't supply an HTML form to work with, I made the following below:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="Textfield1" name="Textfield1" />
    <input type="text" id="Textfield2" name="Textfield2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1" />
    <select id="Select1" name="Select1">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I also refactored your `doGET` method, renaming it `postForm` which accepts a form element as an argument.

```
function postForm(form) {
    var xmlhttp = null,
        data = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        data += '&' + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].id) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value);
    }

    data = data.substr(1); //Get rid of the first character.

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystate = function() { alert(msg); }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "insert.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(data); //Send your data in the send method.
}

postForm(document.getElementById('myForm'));
```

1. We use `POST` instead of `GET` in the `xmlhttp.open` method.
2. We send the parameters just like you did in the GET, but I have automated the serialization of the form with a loop.

Comment: Ok thank you so much!!:) is this ready to use? :) so i can just use `$_POST['Textfield']` on the php?

Comment: it doesnt work. it says 
`Undefined index: e_art_name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\update_article.php</b> on line <b>10`
.
and i used 
`$art =  $_POST['e_art_name'];`

and 
`<input type="button" onClick="postForm(document.getElementById('editform'))" value="d"> ` for the Button

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy, you simply need an iframe in the document with a `name` attribute, and then you can set the `target` on your form to the same value.
When you submit the form, it will then target the iframe.

If you want the form to return something, it can return javascript that accesses the parent using `parent.doSomething` (as long as these are on the same domain).

Comment: That is essentially how AJAX file uploads work in older browsers, but I wouldn't suggest doing this unless that is your goal. The `XmlHttpRequest` gives a much better interface for dealing with AJAX.